# applying primary key to multiple columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have 3 Columns :

```
-> person(varchar(50))
-> related_with(varchar(50))
-> relationship(varchar(50))
```

The combination of above 3 is a primary key

Now for example values are given to 3 columns as :

```
person -> User
related_with -> User1
relationship -> Son of
```

The problem is that if i add values as

```
person -> User1
related_with -> User
relationship -> Son of
```

Then it is inserted successfully .. but this should not be the case since vice versa in this case cant be true

Is there a solution for this problem ??

Comment: please put your table structure and clearify your question

Comment: I bet trigger on INSERT is the solution.

Comment: alter all your 3 columns with unique and restrict person to get only User not User1 it does not make any sense

Comment: Add your table structure here with the constraints

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times, such validations should be made at the application code level. However, if you must do it in database, consider writing a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).

This is indeed a complex logic and the validation (either in application or trigger). There can be various cases:
1. Consider a `relationship -> friend of`. Here a reverse relationship holds true unlike `son of`.

1. Consider a `relationship -> brother of`. In this case, a reverse relation is possible if both the users are male, but not if User is female. Ditto for `relationship -> sister of`.

Hence you need to carefully device a way how you store look up to your relationships and if you want to hard the logic or use flags to identify type of relationship.

Comment: thanks for clarifying ..

can you suggest me a way to make the things work out ?

Answer (score 1):

Make (person, related_with) the key. Mutual relationships like "brother" are implicit so you don't necessarily need two rows to represent them. Now you can add a CHECK constraint:

ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT ck1 CHECK (person < related_with);

That's not a perfect solution for every kind of relationship but it does reduce the amount of redundancy and number of potential anomalies and it enforces the rules declaratively rather than as procedural code in a trigger.